# Думпкар и самосвал

Tags: этимология, история-языка

Чуковский в книге "Живой как жизнь" перечисляет заимствованные слова и возникшие русские эквиваленты, например "голкипер" и "вратарь". Впервые в этом списке встретил слово "думпкар" аналогом которого назван "самосвал". Я сразу подумал о грузовиках-самосвалах, но поискав в современных словарях нашёл только железнодорожные вагоны-самосвалы.

Означал ли когда-нибудь думпкар автомобиль-самосвал? Было ли у автомобилей своё, другое заимствованное название?

Comment: English "dump car" means a railroad car. Russian *самосвал* would be "dump truck" in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если поискать в Google Ngrams слово [самосвал](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=12&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%3B%2Cc0), то слово якобы встречается еще в 1875 году, однако при просмотре детальных результатов оказывается что это ошибки автоматического распознавания (в том числе греческих слов). Есть там и книга 1975 года ошибочно индексированная как 1875, или журнал 1980 проиндексированный как 1930.

Самый первый результат когда употреблено именно слово "самосвал" относится к [1934 году](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80&safe=off&hl=ru&biw=1142&bih=653&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01.01.1900%2Ccd_max%3A31.12.1935&tbm=bks#safe=off&hl=ru&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min:01.01.1900%2Ccd_max:31.12.1935&tbm=bks&q=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB). Похоже это заголовок статьи:

> Румяицев, Г. К. Самоопрокидывающийся кузов (самосвал) для 1,5-т грузовиков ГАЗ-АА.

Если посмотреть в Википедии когда в РСФСР начали производить ГАЗ-АА, то это как раз начало 30-х. Судя по всему изначально слово "самосвал" к грузовику не относилось, а относилось только к его типу кузова. При этом слово дано в скобках, т.е. оно или жаргонное или узкоспециальное. Другими словами слово "самосвал" в значении "грузовой автомобиль оборудованный особым кузовом", на этот момент еще не родилось. Собственно грузовик сам по себе был достаточно новым объектом чтобы делить его на разные специализированные категории.

Другими словами, похоже что заимствованного названия грузовиков-самосвалов не было, так как их первые образцы были самостоятельно изготовлены в России и тут же получили свое название.

Ну и соответственно замена "думпкара" (по ссылке George Shuklin есть пример употребления в 1930-м году) на "самосвал" относилась именно к вагонам-самосвалам, да и то произошла она не окончательно и бесповоротно, так как слово "думпкар" до сих пор используется на железнодорожном транспорте.

Answer (score 4):

Можно утверждать, к 1935ому слово уже использовалось для вагонов: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80&safe=off&hl=ru&biw=1142&bih=653&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01.01.1900%2Ccd_max%3A31.12.1935&tbm=bks

Comment: Спасибо! Судя по "Гаврила крути!" в статье Максима Горького 1930 года, вагоны или вагонетки в карьерах тоже уже так назывались в 1930.